# What is the gardening purpose of an l-shaped groove knife hand tool?

Tags: tools

What is the gardening purpose of an l-shaped groove knife?

[image: l-shaped groove knife]
(credits to http://www.chillingtontoolsonline.com/groove-knife-p62 )

It appears to be a weeding or cultivation tool, a little-bit like a "wrong sided" billhook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used to scratch/cut weeds and moss from small slits like between pavers.

If you search for the term "Patio Weeder", you'll find more pictures like [this](http://img0.reuter.de/products/gar/gardena-combisystem-fugenkratzer-sortiment--gar-03001-20_1.jpg).

Comment: It can also be used as a hand edger next to the sidewalk. :)

Answer (score 3):

The [picture](http://www.chillingtontoolsonline.com/images/products/large/Groove%20Knife.JPG) in the link you provided is a big hint. This tool is for weed removal in crevices between hard surfaces, such as between pavers, sidewalk sections, railroad tie constructions, etc.

It's not designed for regular bed cultivation, and it isn't very efficient for that purpose.