# How to remove unwanted Plants from the garden easily

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, tree-removal, stump-removal

My garden was full of unwanted plants which takes nutrition of my plants. Its growing again and again even after I removing from the garden. Is there anyway I can easily remove the Plants from my garden. So My plants will grow nutritionally.

Comment: A hoe is the usual tool. Twice, while your plants are still small, usually gives them enough of a competitive advantage; around here at lest.

Comment: Did you see this? http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/19619/best-tool-to-remove-weeds/19623#19623

Comment: Easily? Hire a gardener. Otherwise, get out there and weed some more, then mulch.

Comment: I think the question is to broad (and opinion based). I think you should specify your specific case (which kind of unwanted plants), the size of your garden, and maybe the region (climate).

Comment: More than nutrients, usually the weeds take away water from other plants.

Comment: Hi johnie! It looks like the question @Stephie referenced is a duplicate. Is there anything significantly different about yours? If so, feel free to [edit] it in. Thanks!

Comment: I use a shovel to dig under plants with tap roots, like burdock. I pop up the whole root, bang the shovel to loosen the dirt, and pull out the plant out of the shovel roots and all. You must get the root.